# Get Facebook Access Token In Abp Framework

Tags: abp

I am using abp framework with angular and sql server with out of the box identity server.

I have added facebook login which is working fine. Now I need to retrieve the access token returned by facebook login in my application layer for facebook graph api call.

ICurrentUser has no fields for the same.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help: https://support.abp.io/QA/Questions/2604/Social-Logins-with-SaveTokens--true-not-saving-tokens#answer-b2f914ae-a820-c983-4573-3a021d98fec3

Comment: Sure Thanks I will try it out